# How to simplify vector graphics containing a huge number of data points

Tags: graphics

In the genomics field people often produce something called Manhattan plot which consists of points standing for millions of p-values:

[image]

It's very slow for display in vector format, some viewers simply cannot deal with it, but a raster image is much easier to open in this case, but of course we love vector graphics infinitely better ;) .

At the bottom of the plot we can see the density of points are so high that we can join them into a filled area, which should reduce the calculation burden immensely.

How can this be done in TeX? As suggested by one of the answers, it should be possible to get a union of nearby points in a vector graphic editor, but it will take a lot of work. Ideally, one would like to see each point as a path, and during the ploting process, the union operation to be executed point by point, thus in the end the whole plot will be simplified to the largest degree.

Comment: can you provide such a set of data?

Comment: what is the advantage of a vector format here (for the actual plot, not the labels) it seems that the pixels essentially imply a fixed resolution anyway. What is lost if you just use a bitmap image and overlay labels with scalable fonts?

Comment: I would propose preprocessing the data set with a script that removes data points that are completely overdrawn. A complete LaTeX solution seems to be unnecessarily complicated, especially since that would require doing the simplification work every time that you compile the document. The script shouldn't be difficult to write.

Comment: @Herbert It's easy to simulated with R. For example: `p = -log10(runif(1e6, 0, 1)); pdf('x.pdf'); plot(p, pch=20, cex=.5); dev.off()` You will get a pdf file in the current directory. Okular will not open it, Ghostscript viewer `gs` can open it, but very slowly.

Comment: @Ruedi It's not quite easy to preprocess the data either. First you need the size of the point in the plot, then you need to calculate a huge lot of euclidean distances.

Comment: @qed: If I understand it correctly, all points have the same size. So all you need to do is to let R produce a table of the data points, preprocess the table (the computation can be speed up by pre-sorting the points into buckets) using a script and a pre-defined point width and then let the script produce the Tikz or PSTricks Figure.

Comment: @Ruedi yeah, but what if one wants to change the point size? Then everything should be changed again. I would say it's easier to trace out the circumference of the union of all points and fill it, but I don't know exactly how to do this.

Comment: @qed: If you change the point size, then you can just re-run the script to compute the figure from the data points, which will be unchanged.

Comment: @Ruedi thanks, I am trying to implement this in R

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what exactly your R expression really does. However, here is a similiar solution with 50,000 points. Run it with `xelatex` or with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(10,14)
\psset{xunit=0.5}
\psaxes[Dx=2](23,10)
\psplot[plotpoints=50000,plotstyle=dots,dotscale=0.5]{0.01}{23}
   [3 srand]{ x cvi 2 mod 0 eq {0 setgray}{0.5 setgray}ifelse 
              Rand log neg 2 mul 0.6 sub }
\psline[linecolor=blue](0,5)(23,5)
\psline[linecolor=red](0,8)(23,8)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed easier to display even when the number of points are scaled up to 1 million, but still quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to open your output file in a vector editing program, select the plotted points for each area, and take the intersection of them. Doing so would leave you with a single vector for the perimeter of each plot area.

This assumes the dots in the file are rendered as small overlapping circles rather than as points with some corresponding diameter.

I agree with both David and Ruedi that the image just needs to be simplified once instead of being processed repeatedly upon compilation of the document.

Comment: I would say to do the union instead of intersections.

Comment: It's going to be hard time for the vector editing program.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a LaTeX solution but I've recently found a way of producing moderately-sized Manhattan plots as vector graphics exported to PDF with the R packages [`sf`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) and [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/). These can then easily be included in a LaTeX document.

Similarly to what @Steven Endres suggested, my approach is to perform a union of overlapping points so as to decrease the complexity of the final figure (the large areas made of mostly overlapping points become a single shape for each chromosome).

I've made an R function to make these simplified Manhattan plots from a set of summary statistics [available on GitHub](https://github.com/linoferreira/manhattan-vector). The repo also includes a reproducible example.